# inductive set and examples

Tags: real-analysis

I want a simple definition which is easy to understand of "*Inductive Set*"

1. What is the meaning of $< \mathbb{Z}^+$ is a subset of every inductive set $>$?
2. What is the meaning of $< \mathbb{R}$ is a inductive set? So is the set $\mathbb{R}^+>$?

I have encountered this definition in the book Mathematical Analysis by Tom Apostol.

Comment: Your question was put on hold, the message above (and possibly comments) should give an explanation why. You might try to edit your question to address these issues. Note that the next edit puts your post in the review queue, where users can vote to reopen this. (Therefore it would be good to avoid minor edits and improve your question as much as possible with the next edit.)

Comment: It seems that the question got [somehow reopened](http://math.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/425759). I still think that it would be better if you were more precisely what exactly is unclear to you. But I tried to post an answer, maybe what I wrote might help you clarify things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Apostol's book the following definitions of an inductive set is given.

> **Definition 1.3.** A set of real numbers is called an inductive set if it has the following two properties:
>   a) The number $1$ is in the set.
>   b) For every $x$ in the set, the number $x+1$ is also in the set.

It is true that both the set $\mathbf R$ of all real numbers and the set $\mathbf R^+$ of all positive real numbers are inductive. The number $1$ belongs to both of them. If $x$ is a real number, then so is $x+1$. If $x>0$ then also $x+1>0$.

---

He then defines positive integers as follows:

> **Definition 1.4.** A real number is called a positive integer if it belongs to every inductive set. The set of positive integers is denoted by $\mathbf Z^+$.

So if this is our working definition of the set $\mathbf Z^+$, then the fact that $\mathbf Z^+$ is a subset of every inductive set $I$ is very easy.

Just recall what is the definition of a [subset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset). To see that $\mathbf Z^+\subseteq I$, where $I$ is inductive set, you just need to check whether every element $x\in\mathbf Z^+$  belong to $I$ too. But this is precisely the definition -- the set $\mathbf Z^+$ contains precisely those elements which belong to each inductive set (according to Definition 1.4.)